# Is it okay to forward cookies to an external backend using Axios interceptors in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I have a collection of API's written in Laravel. For every CRUD operation an access token is required.

I've created an Axios instance to make HTTP requests inside server components and server actions. But the problem is every time I use the Axios instance I should pass the cookies as well.

```
// src/app/dashboard/page.tsx

import axios from "@/services/index";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { AUTH_KEY } from "@/constants/keys";

async function Page() {
    const users = await axios.get("users", {
        headers: {
            Authorization: cookies().get(AUTH_KEY)?.value
        }
    });

    return null;
}

export default Page;
```

**This really has a bad DX**.

So the solution that I could think of was to make use of Axios interceptors like the code below.

```
// src/services/index.ts

import _axios from "axios";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { AUTH_KEY } from "@/constants/keys";

const axios = _axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
});

axios.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
        config.headers.Authorization = cookies().get(AUTH_KEY)?.value;
        return config;
    }
);
```

Now for each request made to the Laravel backend the interceptor will read the access token from the cookie and puts it into the HTTP header.

Is this a good pattern? Is there a better approach to take?